# Hover state remains after scrolling

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm having a weird behavior on the browser.

From the following example try this:

1. Move the cursor to the rectangle area. The rectangle will turn red
2. Do not move the mouse but just scrolling down until the cursor gets out of the screen.
3. Observe.

The rectangle is still red.
Does anyone know how to figure this out?

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 2000px;
}

.rect {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.rect:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rect" onmouseleave="console.log('mouseleave');">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It may because hover-out is when mouse is moved and on scroll mouse is on steady state

Comment: The behavior is normal here? on Firefox from your snippet. But just to be clear: what did you mean with "until the cursor gets out of the screen."?

Comment: It looks like it doesn't happen on Firefox, but it happens on Chrome

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an intentional behaviour. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/KIoVljZw5fc/m/EKGAoTeX8CQJ?pli=1

The catch here is the mouse is not actually leaving ,only the page is scrolling, the mouse pointer stays in the same position.

This behaviour tradeoff is mainly for performance reasons.